# Executing cmd file contained in a folder with space

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to run the cmd file using JDK7u25 with following code:

```
try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            pb.directory(workingDir);
            proc = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        // StdOut and Err Stream must be read immediatly even if they are not used

        // any error message?
        StreamInlet error = new StreamInlet(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");

        // any output?
        StreamInlet output = new StreamInlet(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

        // kick them off
        error.start();
        output.start();

        if (wait) {
            try {
                exitCode = proc.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for process was interrupted");
            }
            if (addMetaInfo)
                System.out.println("Return value = " + exitCode);
        }
```

where `cmd=[cmd.exe, /c, C:\My Root\scripts\windows\tools\MyCLI.cmd, -c, C:\Local Disk D\My Tutorial\RegressionTests.xml, -d, 02_RecordViewer_Test, -l"ERROR"]`

But it doesn't work and I get following output.

> 'C:\My' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.

I have already made the necessary changes for [JDK7U21 issue](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#jruntime) by adding explicit "CMD.EXE /C" before calling the cmd file. Also I am using the ProcessBuilder class too as mentioned in the JDK7u21 issue.

It works fine if the cmd file I am trying to execute is placed in C:\MyRoot i.e. a folder without space in it's name.

Can someone please help?

Comment: That's because `cmd` requires paths enclosed in quotation marks `"C:\My Root\scripts\windows\tools\MyCLI.cmd"` and `"C:\Local Disk D\My Tutorial\RegressionTests.xml"` by Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose your paths in quotation marks as `cmd` requires:

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "\"C:\\My Root\\scripts\\windows\\tools\\MyCLI.cmd\"", "-c", "\"C:\\Local Disk D\\My Tutorial\\RegressionTests.xml\"",.....};
```

**Update**  as we discussed via chat, the problem seems to be `ProcessBuilder` passing parameters to `cmd.exe`. But as you have the complete path to your executable, actually `cmd.exe` is no needed at all. So the command would look like this:

```
String[] cmd = {"\"C:\\My Root\\scripts\\windows\\tools\\MyCLI.cmd\"", "-c", "\"C:\\Local Disk D\\My Tutorial\\RegressionTests.xml\"",.....};
```

Comment: cmd is a String[]. The value of cmd I put in question is the value I get when I debug it from eclipse. I also tried with enclosing it in double quotes as you mentioned above. But no luck :(

Comment: But you're getting the same error? Please post how do you call the same command in a `cmd` console and check if it works.

Comment: If I call it explicitly (by enclosing in quotes) from cmd console it works. But the same command line doesn't work from java.

Comment: Try making your command (which works in a console) in a single String: `String myCommand = "\"C:\\My Root\\scripts\\windows\\tools\\MyCLI.cmd\" -c \"C:\\Local Disk D\\My Tutorial\\RegressionTests.xml\" -d 02_RecordViewer_Test -l\"ERROR\"";` and then call `ProcessBuilder` like this: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c",myCommand)`

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work too. Can you re-produce this issue at your end too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35600/discussion-between-paragj-and-dic19)

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that this issue has already been addressed in JDK7u25. I just found it in it's [Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html#jruntime).

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to change the backslashes to forwards slashes, and escape the spaces.

```
C:/My\ Root/scripts/windows/tools/MyCLI.cmd
```