# Running pan.bat from command line

Tags: environment-variables, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm trying to run pan.bat through cmd from my windows os system,I have set the environment variable PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME,seeking help for the same , Thanking in advance.

[image]

I tried this command to run the .ktr

```
C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration>pan.bat /file:E:\Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT\dynamic pivot\trying_pivot_with_2_billingid.ktr /level:Basic
```

and this is the error I'm getting

```
 WARNING: Using java from path
```

DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=java.exe
C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration>"java.exe"  "-Xmx1024m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_R
EPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-a
pplication-launcher-5.2.0.0-209.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan /file:E:\Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT\dynamic pivot\trying_pi
vot_with_2_billingid.ktr /level:Basic
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
2016/03/03 16:46:55 - Pan - Logging is at level : Basic logging
2016/03/03 16:46:55 - Pan - Start of run.
Processing has stopped because of an error:
Unable to read file [file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION]
Could not read from "file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION" because it is a not a file.

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:
Unable to read file [file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION]
Could not read from "file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION" because it is a not a file.

```
    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:559)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:538)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2660)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2628)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2605)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2585)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2550)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2513)
    at org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan.main(Pan.java:380)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileNotFoundException: Could not read from "file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION" because it is a not a file.
        at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.DefaultFileContent.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getInputStream(KettleVFS.java:247)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:557)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Practise_TRANSFORMATION (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.local.LocalFile.doGetInputStream(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more

I have done echo %PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME% to verify

```
C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration>echo %PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%
```

%PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%

C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration>

Answer (score 0):

Low hanging fruit. Using a console command like:

```
C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration>pan.bat /file:E:\Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT\dynamic pivot\trying_pivot_with_2_billingid.ktr /level:Basic
```

you are have folder name with spaces -

```
Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT
```

try

```
Practise_TRANSFORMATION^ OUTPUT
```

there is different approaches to deal with cmd and file names with spaces. See [Executing cmd file contained in a folder with space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273007/executing-cmd-file-contained-in-a-folder-with-space) as example.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing space from my folder by making it to Practise_TRANSFORMATION_OUTPUT.but unfortunately the there is another error.

Comment: I have posted my question of what exactly the error is. here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787982/error-while-running-pan-bat-in-command-line