# error while running pan.bat in command line

Tags: command-line, cmd, pentaho, kettle, pdi

[with the reference to my previous post,here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770956/running-pan-bat-from-command-line/35774511#35774511)

I'm still yet facing with some errors. I tried running other .ktr file it ran successfully but when I'm trying to run "pivot_inject_etl_metadata.ktr" it gives me following error

```
 C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration>pan.bat /file:E:\Practise_TRANSFORMATION_OUTPUT\dynamic_pivot\pivot_inject_etl_metadata.ktr /level:Basic 
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe

C:\pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe"  "-Xmx256m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-
DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-5.2.0.0-209.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main
org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan /file:E:\Practise_TRANSFORMATION_OUTPUT\dynamic_pivot\pivot_inject_etl_metadata.ktr /level:Basic
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - Pan - Logging is at level : Basic logging
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - Pan - Start of run.
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - pivot_inject_etl_metadata - Dispatching started for transformation [pivot_inject_etl_metadata]
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Bad encoding!
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Unable to load transformation ///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic pivot/pivot_inject.ktr from file.
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Unable to read file [file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic pivot/pivot_inject.ktr]
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Could not read from "file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic pivot/pivot_inject.ktr" because it is a not a file.
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.metainject.MetaInjectMeta.loadTransformationMeta(MetaInjectMeta.java:443)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.metainject.MetaInject.init(MetaInject.java:403)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepInitThread.run(StepInitThread.java:69)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Unable to read file [file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic pivot/pivot_inject.ktr]
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Could not read from "file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic pivot/pivot_inject.ktr" because it is a not a file.
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:559)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:538)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2660)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.metainject.MetaInjectMeta.loadTransformationMeta(MetaInjectMeta.java:438)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        ... 3 more
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileNotFoundException: Could not read from "file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic pivot/pivot_inject.ktr"
 because it is a not a file.
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.DefaultFileContent.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getInputStream(KettleVFS.java:247)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:557)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        ... 6 more
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT\dynamic pivot\pivot_inject.ktr (The system cannot find the file specified)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.local.LocalFile.doGetInputStream(Unknown Source)
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -        ... 10 more
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [ETL Metadata Injection]
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - pivot_inject_etl_metadata - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Step [ETL Metadata Injection.0] failed to initialize!
Unable to prepare and initialize this transformation
```

can I have a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: [Running pan.bat from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770956/running-pan-bat-from-command-line) in one of comment you wrote:

"Thanks, I tried removing space from my folder by making it to Practise_TRANSFORMATION_OUTPUT.but unfortunately the there is another error."

and then you got error:

```
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 -
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Unable to read file [file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic pivot/pivot_inject.ktr]
2016/03/04 09:46:41 - ETL Metadata Injection.0 - Could not read from "file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic pivot/pivot_inject.ktr" because it is a not a file.
```

once againt -

```
Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT
```

Incorrect folder hard-coded for transformation reference. I suppose should be

```
Practise_TRANSFORMATION_OUTPUT
```

Please check after you rename some folder - all other manually hard-coded paths is also updated. Use repository. 
If you still don't use repository - but want to reference one transformation from other under same folder - use variable called:

```
${Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory}
```

for transformations and

```
${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}
```

for jobs accordingly. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an error message I got in yours.

Could not read from "file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic 
pivot/pivot_inject.ktr" because it is a not a file.

You should check:
- whether the pivot_inject.ktr file exists in E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic or not
pivot
- whether the pivot_inject.ktr file is correct format or not..

You can do it by simply copy: file:///E:/Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT/dynamic 
pivot/pivot_inject.ktr and paste on the window explorer or web browser

Comment: the file pivot_inject does exist on the specified path, I'm not been able to understand that why it is showing SPACE in between TRANSFORMATION & OUTPUT. If you see the first line of my command there isn't any space between TRANSFORMATION & OUTPUT and between dynamic & pivot.

Comment: There is a space between Practise_TRANSFORMATION OUTPUT, you can try to create another folder without space? Secondly, the pivot_inject.ktr should be an xml file. You can open the file by notepad/notepad++ to check if the content of file is correct

Answer (score 0):

The first error message on your log is " ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Bad encoding!"

I'm dought about the encoding of the file "pan.bat" .

Comment: so how do I check the the correctness of pan.bat file? what's the further resolution.

Answer (score 0):

hey hi all thanks for all your assistance, I guess I founded out the reason behind that error, I believe this is the most silliest reason that I didn't change the source file path in "CSV Input" step and didn't properly specified the "pivot_inject.ktr" path.
Thanks once again.
 [image]